# How to add JIRA board quick filter query for severity?

Tags: jira

I am flabbergasted but none of these queries seems to work.

```
"Defect Severity" = "critical"
"Defect Severity" = "1-critical"
"Defect Severity" = "Critical"
"Defect Severity" = critical
"Defect Severity" = 1-Critical
"Defect Severity" = "1"
```

I spent 30 mins browsing the web and Atlassian for examples..none.

It says:

> The option '1-Critical' for field 'Defect Severity' does not exist.

for each of those..Why?

Answer (score 2):

That is because the field name you are looking for is likely "priority" and not "severity". Here is the query I use to find any blockers in QA:

```
status = "Ready for QA" AND priority = Blocker ORDER BY created ASC, updatedDate ASC
```

"Priority" can equal "Blocker", "Severe", "Major", "Minor", or "Trivial".

Check out the official documentation on [how to use advanced filters](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching) in JIRA.